# Remove Part of a sentence within an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using wpdiscuz pluggin for WordPress and I want to remove a part of the content of the `.wc-comment-title`, that is, remove the part of a sentence within a paragraph with jQuery or JavaScript.

This is the code:

```
<p class="wc-comment-title">
<span class="wc_header_text_count">4>/span>
"Comments on "Article 1""
</p>
```

It displays: **4 Comments on "Article 1"**

and I would like to make it: **4 Comments**

The number of comments and the name of the article change according to the number of comments and the article in question, it is dinamic.

Ex: **3** Comments on "**Blog Post 4**"

In that case I want it to display : **3 Comments**

Is it possible?

Comment: Are the number of comments coming from an API or is it purely Client side ?

Comment: It is purely client side as the name of the articles. The only thin I want is to remove the name of the article. The 'on' before the article I can do it in the phrases settings of the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `wc_header_text_count` class, you can use `.nextSibling` to get the adjacent text node. Text nodes have a number of methods available for manipulating their content, but since you seem to just want to have the text `Comments` in its place, you can just replace it altogether.

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".wc_header_text_count")

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].nextSibling.data = " Comments";
}
```

```html
<p class="wc-comment-title">
<span class="wc_header_text_count">4</span>
"Comments on "Article 1""
</p>

<p class="wc-comment-title">
<span class="wc_header_text_count">3</span>
"Comments on "Blog Post 4""
</p>
```

If you didn't necessarily want "Comments" but rather wanted the first word without a quotation mark, you could use a regex.

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".wc_header_text_count")

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].nextSibling.data = 
    spans[i].nextSibling.data.replace(/^\s*"?(\w+)[\s\S]*$/, " $1");
}
```

```html
<p class="wc-comment-title">
<span class="wc_header_text_count">4</span>
"Comments on "Article 1""
</p>

<p class="wc-comment-title">
<span class="wc_header_text_count">3</span>
"Comments on "Blog Post 4""
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you:) I am going to try it out:)

Comment: I just have to wait one minute to accept your answer:)

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just replace the trailing text with " Comments"? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6o3wha9g/

```
$('.wc-comment-title').contents().last()[0].textContent=' Comments';
```

Comment: YES:) It also works. Your 'simple' jQuery sentence could have been accepted answer as well. Just a few minutes late. But for everyone out there with a similar question: THIS ALSO WORKS!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: The only difference is that when it has 0 comments it only displays 'Comments' though, not '0 Comments'